# The process cannot access the file on terminal server c#

Tags: c#, terminal-services

I was asked to write programm, which **get the Application's files from ftp** and then start that Application. On local machines it works fine, but on terminal-services users *on second run* it throws: **The process cannot access the file because it is beign used by another process.**

This method **updates** files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace fmstart {
    class fmUpd {
        private static  string updFile="fmupdate.inf";
        private static string tmpPath = @"C:\Program Files\SRZNerpa\FinMagic\";

        public static void Update()
        {
            FTPClient ftpCl=new FTPClient(@"ftp://srz-web.nerpa.srz:21/FM2Update/","anonymous", "anonymous");
            FileStream updateStream=File.Create(tmpPath+updFile);
            ftpCl.DownloadFile(updFile,updateStream);
            updateStream.Flush();
            updateStream.Close();
            IEnumerable<string> updFiles=File.ReadLines(tmpPath+updFile);
            foreach (string fileName in updFiles) {
                if (fileName!=String.Empty) {
                    FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\Program Files\SRZNerpa\FinMagic\" + fileName.Trim(),1024);
                    ftpCl.DownloadFile(fileName, fs);
                    fs.Flush();
                    fs.Close(); 
                    fs.Dispose();
                    GC.Collect();   
                }
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

And this code **start** updated App:

```
fmUpd.Update();
ProcessStartInfo fm = new ProcessStartInfo();
fm.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\SRZNerpa\FinMagic\finmagic.exe";
fm.UseShellExecute = true;
Process Proc = Process.Start(fm);
Application.Exit();
```

Any ideas how to make it work on terminal-services stations?
Thank you.